# creating diagonal matrix with selected elements

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

I have a `4x5` matrix called `A` from which I want to select randomly 3 rows, then 4 random columns and then select those elements which coincide in those selected rows and columns so that I have 12 selected elements.Then I want to create a diagonal matrix called `B` which will have entries either 1 or 0 so that multiplication of that `B` matrix with reshaped `A` matrix (`20x1`) will give me those selected 12 elements of `A`.

How can I create that `B` matrix? Here is my code:

```
A=1:20;
A=reshape(A,4,5);
Mr=4;
Ma=3;
Na=4;
Nr=5;
M=Ma*Mr;
[S1,S2]=size(A);
N=S1*S2;
y2=zeros(size(A));
k1=randperm(S1);
k1=k1(1:Ma);
k2=randperm(S2);
k2=k2(1:Mr);
y2(k1,k2)=A(k1,k2);
```

Comment: @Adriaan  yapp sorry I edited it.

Comment: You can't have a diagonal matrix that will solve this problem.  You can populate certain values of `B` to achieve what you want with the multiplication, but it certainly won't be diagonal.  Multiplying a matrix that is diagonal with a vector will simply return scaled components of that vector... unless it is your intention to replace those values not selected with 0 in the final vector.  Please clarify if you actually mean a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @rayryeng I think he means the diagonal matrix will have a `0` for values it shouldn't return and a `1` for values it should. The result of `A*B` will be a 20 element vector with 12 non-zero values due to the `1`'s in `B`. Sorry that probably doesn't help you but a diagonal matrix will solve the problem although I don't know why `B` cant be a vector and element by element multiplication being used.

Comment: @IKavanagh that's true, which is why I'm confused... and that's why I haven't written an answer yet.

Comment: @rayryeng I just wrote one. Trying to learn `bsxfun` and this seemed like a nice place to employ it!

Comment: @rayryeng I think you did not get what I mean.In my code y2 gives that selected 12 elements of A.Now I want a diagonal matrix B (which will have size 12x20) with entries 0 and 1 so that B*A(:) will give me a 12x1 matrix which are the same elements of y2 which are not zero.

Comment: So what you want is `B` where `y3 = A*B` and `y3 = y2(y2 ~= 0)`?  This question is very unclear.  Pretty sure `B` cannot be diagonal for the example you have provided.

Comment: @Matt  Please run the code which I have provided and compare matrix A and y2! that elements in y2 which are not zero are that elements which I have selected randomly from A (12 elements). Now I need that B matrix which is diagonal with entries either 0 or 1 so that B*A(:) will also give me that 12 elements

Comment: `idx = reshape(y2 ~= 0, numel(y2), [])`.  Then `A(idx)` will give you want you want.  No diagonal needed.  I ran your code.  Your desire for `B` is useless.  There are better ways to do it.

Comment: @Matt  I need that diagonal B matrix because it is used in the rest of my main code. I have to generate it!

Comment: For reference http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiagonalMatrix.html what you are asking for is NOT a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 4):

It's a little hard to understand what you want and your code isn't much help but I think I've a solution for you.

I create a matrix (vector) of zeros of the same size as `A` and then use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to determine the indexes in this vector (which will be the diagonal of `B`) that should be `1`.

```
>> A = reshape(1:20, 4, 5);
>> R = [1 2 3]; % Random rows
>> C = [2 3 4 5]; % Random columns
>> B = zeros(size(A));
>> B(bsxfun(@plus, C, size(A, 1)*(R-1).')) = 1;
>> B = diag(B(:));
>> V = B*A(:);
>> V = V(V ~= 0)
V =
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
    10
    11
    12
    13
```

---

**Note**: There is no need for `B = diag(B(:));` we could have simply used element by element multiplication in Matlab.

```
>> V = B(:).*A(:);
>> V = V(V ~= 0)
```

---

**Note**: This may be overly complex or very poorly put together and there is probably a better way of doing it. It's my first real attempt at using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) on my own.

Comment: Welcome to the world of `bsxfun`.  Your brethren await you, with Divakar as our #1!

Comment: `bsxfun` is so much fun!

Comment: guys I didnt get what it is about but I dont need the output selected 12 elements. Actually I need that diagonal B matrix. And also here I wrote a sample A matrix.in real my matrix has size of 512x512 so that creating that B matrix will be impossible and I think I should use sparse function.Am I right?

Comment: @Nanor I'm really confused. Why do you need a diagonal matrix? Can you not use element by element multiplication?

Comment: @IKavanagh because that diagonal matrix B is also used in other part of my main code.So I need to have it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hack but since you are creating `y2` you might as well just use it instead of creating the useless `B` matrix.  The `bsxfun` answer is much better.

```
A=1:20;
A=reshape(A,4,5);
Mr=4;
Ma=3;
Na=4;
Nr=5;
M=Ma*Mr;
[S1,S2]=size(A);
N=S1*S2;
y2=zeros(size(A));
k1=randperm(S1);
k1=k1(1:Ma);
k2=randperm(S2);
k2=k2(1:Mr);
y2(k1,k2)=A(k1,k2);
idx = reshape(y2 ~= 0, numel(y2), []);
B = diag(idx);
% "diagonal" matrix 12x20
B = B(all(B==0,2),:) = [];
output = B * A(:)
```

output =

```
 1
 3
 4
 9
11
12
13
15
16
17
19
20
```

y2 from example.

```
y2 =

 1     0     9    13    17
 0     0     0     0     0
 3     0    11    15    19
 4     0    12    16    20
```